# Redirect user after login to prior page through a wp_login hook

Tags: redirect, login

We store user meta data on our website. I have a function hooked into the wp_login action to redirect the user to a form to update their meta if it's older than 1 year. If the user's information is up to date, I want to redirect to the page they were at when they first clicked "Log in". I haven't been able to figure this out though. For now, I just redirect to the home page (in the last "else" statement). Any ideas?

Thank you!

Edit: Essentially, I need some way to run a custom function that executes as the user is navigating to the login page through the link generated by the wp_loginout() function. This custom function should store the prior link, maybe via something like `$redirect = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`

```
function check_user_info($username) { 
  $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
  // Get current user ID  
  $wp_user_id=$user->ID;  
  // Unix display of times
  $current_time_unix= time();
  //add_user_meta($wp_user_id,'test4','test5',TRUE);
  $last_update_unix=get_user_meta($wp_user_id, 'last_updated', TRUE);
  $next_update_unix=get_user_meta($wp_user_id, 'next_update_request', TRUE);  
  // Nice display of times 
  $current_time = date('F j, Y H:i:s',$current_time_unix);
  $last_update_time = date('F j, Y H:i:s',$last_update_unix);
  $next_update_time = date('F j, Y H:i:s',$next_update_unix);
  // Echo Last / Next update time
  // echo "current time: ".$current_time."<br>";
  // echo "last update: ".$last_update_time."<br>";
  // echo "next update: ".$next_update_time."<br>";

  // If meta doesn't exist, must be a new user through social login, redirect
  if (!$last_update_unix) {
    //echo 'redirect';
    wp_redirect("https://eyeguru.org/register/?type=new_user_from_social_login");
    exit;
  } 
  // if meta exists, and the user information is 1+ years old, redirect 
  if ($last_update_unix && $current_time_unix>$next_update_unix) {
    //echo 'redirect';
    wp_redirect("https://eyeguru.org/register/?type=update_expired_info");
    exit;
  }
  // if meta exists, and the user information is up to date, redirect to homepage
  else {
    wp_redirect("https://eyeguru.org/");
    exit;
  }

}
add_action('wp_login', 'check_user_info');
```

Comment: Let me know what exactly problem you have been facing with above code???

Comment: Hi Tanmay. The above code works, but I need some way to have the last else statement redirect to the page immediately before the login screen, rather than the home page. I think I need to write a function to store the prior address as the user is navigating to the login screen. But can't find a hook to use. The problem with this code is that the wp_login hook runs after the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the page where the user is coming from using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` and replace your redirect to the homepage like below:

```
// if meta exists, and the user information is up to date, redirect to homepage
  else {
    $redirect = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jekayode, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I think it's because the "check_user_info" function is hooked into "wp_login", which runs after the user actually logs in. Therefore, address used for referer is stored as the login page itself, rather than the page before the login page.